# Pointer Error with C

Tags: c, pointers

I have just started experimenting with pointers in C using Visual Studio IDE.

I have written this simple program in an attempt to get 10 numbers from the user, store them in memory by using pointers and imitating a standard 1D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *nums;

void main() {
    printf("Enter 10 numbers");
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", *(nums + i));
    }
    printf("Number are: ");
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        printf(" %d,", *(nums + i));
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF698C7190C in Assignment 1D.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `nums`. Also, this doesn't look like C++.

Comment: the `nums` pointer is not initialized and it points to some random location.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  it's actually initialized to zero, as all global scope variables are by definition.

Comment: @RussSchultz, correct, but 0 is still not a valid memory address.

Comment: @crush Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  Actually, 0 is a valid memory address.   ARM processors, for example, generally have their vector tables out of reset at 0, and there's stuff there that needs to be read by the processor and/or boot code.  By convention, however, most systems try to not use it so the whole NULL pointer expectations work, and most larger systems (i.e. linux and windows) set up the MMU so that accesses cause exceptions.

Comment: @RussSchultz: The reset vector is not part of the C language. Even more, as the SP is not initialised at that time. An environment might make address 0 very well invalid. However, you are right, a null pointer is not the same as address `0` either and you are right, the C standard does not reserve any specific address value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reserve memory where you are going to store entered values.

Take into account that this statement

```
scanf_s("%d", *(nums + i));
```

is also wrong. The argument of `scanf` must be a pointer.

The program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main( void ) 
{
    int nums[N];

    printf( "Enter %d numbers: ", N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        scanf_s( "%d", nums + i );
    }

    printf( "Number are: " );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf(" %d,", *( nums + i) );
    }
}
```

Another approach is to allocate the array dynamically.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main( void ) 
{
    int *nums = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );

    printf( "Enter %d numbers: ", N );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        scanf_s( "%d", nums + i );
    }

    printf( "Number are: " );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf(" %d,", *( nums + i) );
    }

    free( nums );
}
```

As for this error

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF698C7190C in Assignment 1D.exe: 0xC0000005:
 Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000
```

then as you did not allocate memory then the pointer `nums` as it has the static storage duration was initialized by the system by zero. And the error message says that you are trying to access memory at address 0 (0x0000000000000000)

Answer (score 2):

You need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *nums;

void main() {    
    nums = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));    // <<< allocate memory for 10 ints

    printf("Enter 10 numbers");
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", (nums + i));      // <<< (nums + i) is already a pointer
    }
    printf("Number are: ");
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        printf(" %d,", *(nums + i));
    }
}
```

You should read about memory allocation.

BTW instead of writing `*(nums + i)` you can write `nums[i]` which is strictly equivalent but more readable.

Comment: Could also use `calloc(10,sizeof(int))` for a nicely initialized array.